No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>
function MapComponent({ position, popupData }) {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    map.setView(position, map.getZoom());
  }, [position, map]);
  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={13}
        style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution="© OpenStreetMap contributors"
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            {popupData.city}, {popupData.country}
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
}


I'm using react-leaflet and I added a marker with an event Handler on click to zoom to this marker , but when I try to use const map=useMap() all I get is this error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
